# Need to replace the text starting with the word "Designation:" and upto the end

Tags: jquery

There is a  tag inside it, there is some text, I need to replace the text starting with the text "Designation: SME" the Designation may change i.e. it may be "Designation : Senior CTO", So I need to select all the text starting with "Designation : ......" and replace it with some other text.

For e.g. the HTML is as shown below:

```
<span id="lblEmployee">EMP No: 123456789
  </br>
  </br>
  *Designation:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Senior CTO*
</span>
```

Now, I need to replace the text inside the ** i.e. the text starting with "Designation....." up to the end i.e. CTO

Please suggest on what is the JQuery I can use to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `replace` with regex:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log($('#lblEmployee').text().replace(/Designation:.*/, 'nextext'))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="lblEmployee">EMP No: 123456789
  </br>
  </br>
  Designation:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Senior CTO
</span>
```

Comment: Is the * before Designation a wildcard character ?

Comment: Yes it is, `\s*` if for zero or more space.

Comment: I have added the * in the start and end just to mark and highlight it, there may not be such characters

Comment: It was not very clear but it doesn't make much difference. When you provide sample code don't insert `*`, just add js comments. I edited.

Comment: Please take a look at [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: I have added it as data.innerHTML.replace(/Designation:*/, 'Status1:    ' + newVal)

but it doesn't replace the text after Designation, the old text still exists, it means the wildcard doesn't work, is this the right syntax for wildcards ?

Comment: `Designation:*` means `Designation` followed by zero or more `:`. If you want to match `Designation:` and ALL characters after it, use `Designation:.*` (any number of any character after `Designation`.

Comment: Have already completed it and works fine, thank you, just saw your comments, I was missing the . before *

Comment: Any idea on telerik Radgrid controls ?